# pam_exec.so doesn't write password to script when expose_authtok is enabled

Tags: openssh, pam

We are using PAM for authenticating with external radius server. We have the following line in /etc/pam.d/common-auth

auth    [success=6 default=ignore]      pam_exec.so expose_authtok /home/cliuser/radiusAuth.sh

PAM writes the password to stdin of the script and provides the user name as an environment variable.

This was working till libpam-modules version 1.1.1-6.1. After upgrading to 1.1.3-7.1, the password is coming as empty when I try to read in script. We are using open-ssh as our ssh server.

Thanks, Prasanth

Answer (score 8):

**Short Answer**

I was experiencing this issue and the problem was that there was a policy in /etc/ssh/sshd_config that was being violated.  Mine was that AllowUsers was set and I was trying to log in as a user that did not already exist on the system.

**Longer Answer**

The longer answer is that the password was being overwritten. It was not actually coming in as empty.  It just so happened that the first line had a non displayable backspace character(^H) and a new line.  The read command I was using was only reading the first line into the variable.  After using cat on stdin the full contents (as shown by vim with :set list) was

```
"^H$
^M^?INCORRECT^@"
```

The dollar sign being a new line.

After some digging we found this in the openssh source code

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/df56a8035d429b2184ee94aaa7e580c1ff67f73a/auth-pam.c#L1198

Which shows the password being overwritten by

https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/df56a8035d429b2184ee94aaa7e580c1ff67f73a/auth-pam.c#L234

Which contains the characters we expected.  The comments explain why:

```
/*
 * If the user logging in is invalid, or is root but is not permitted
 * by PermitRootLogin, use an invalid password to prevent leaking
 * information via timing (eg if the PAM config has a delay on fail).
 */
```

The validation logic used to mark authctxt->valid as false is here
https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/df56a8035d429b2184ee94aaa7e580c1ff67f73a/auth.c#L98

Which lays out all the reasons the user/password may be invalid.

Edit: I've updated the links to lock to a particular commit so that they would remain correct. Although the code has changed the behavior has not.

Answer (score 1):

Another common mistake/misconception is how to get the password from pam which is passed on stdin.  The easiest way I have seen is

```
PASS=`cat -`
```

.  The more common method of reading from arguments such as $@, $1, etc  DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: On Debian (bash) is seem you have to use `PASS="$(cat -)"`. But I still have a null issue, I'm getting the error `warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`